# MvvmCross binding UIImageView to Byte[]

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross

I am pretty sure there is a pre-built converter for binding a byte array to a UIImageView but i am having trouble finding it.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of samples that do this:

- the PictureTaking sample using a *built-in* `InMemoryImage` converter - [FirstView.cs#L27](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/PictureTaking/PictureTaking.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs#L27) - this *built-in* converter is only available in the PictureChooser plugin - see [MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Touch/MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter.cs)
- the FractalGen sample uses a custom ValueConverter - [GenerateView.cs#L26](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/FractalGen/FractalGen.UI.Touch/Views/GenerateView.cs#L26) and [BytesToUIImageConverter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/FractalGen/FractalGen.UI.Touch/Converters/BytesToUIImageConverter.cs)